# How can I change the hotspot name without changing the iPhone name?

Tags: ios, tethering

How can I change the hotspot name without changing the iPhone name (the name indicated in `Settings > General > About`)?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple confirmed in their own forums the only way to do this is by changing the phone name.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7828399

Comment: discussions.apple.com is an Apple users forum, not an official Apple publication. While Apple employees moderate (user/customer rants are removed quickly), they rarely weigh in; when they do so, they identify themselves and only suggest how users might approach problems. The cited thread is therefore a customer comment or answer, not an Apple one.

Comment: Did you read the page? Apple tagged it as the recommended solution. Non-Apple users can’t mark anything as “Apple Recommended”.

Comment: you're quite right - I didn't see the notation, and now also see that as it doesn't appear in all answers, it's reasonable to assume that someone at Apple applied this approval.